# Laravel filter relation with where returns all

Tags: laravel-5, collections, filter, eloquent, relationship

I try to filter my users by role in a subquery but returns all records

here I have a normal Model query which I extend with a subquery if the request contains the position parameter

```
$query = User::select()-> ....
```

and here comes the extension on `$request->has('position')`

```
if ($request->has('position')) {
            $role = $request->get('position');

            if ($role == 'all') {
                $query->with('roles');
            } else {
                $query->with(['roles' => function($query) use($role) {
                     $query->where('id', $role);
                }]);
            }
        } else {
            $query->with('roles');
        }
```

but this one returns the filtered and plus other users

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using `whereHas` model method, here is the hole refactoring

```
if ($request->has('position')) {
    $role = $request->get('position');
    if ($role !== 'all' && $role !== 0 ) {
        $query->whereHas('roles', function($query) use($role) {
             return $query->where('id', $role);
        });
    }
}
```